# What have you used Makefiles for (besides build automation)

Tags: scripting, automation, linux

Makefiles are great for automating builds, installs and tests.

But, that is not the end of Make. I have used makefiles to do many tasks like cleaning up logs, keeping mirrored web pages and downloads, hooked them into crontabs and test suites...

Like scripting, I think there is a large scope of automating with Makefiles. Particularly when you have a chain of dependency based triggering required.

What different things have you done using Makefiles?
What are you planning to do more with them, on a rainy day perhaps.

Answer (score 6):

My resume.  LaTeX input, PDF output.

Answer (score 4):

I like Makefiles very much, especially for junior sysadmins.

**Update the bind zonefile?**

No problem: target has `checkzone` and `checkconfig` (out of memory) and only does `sudo cp <editlocation> <reallocation>; git commit -a ....` if everything seems basically fine...

***Complex* deployment?**

No problem record it in a Makefile

I've pretty much used Makefiles anywhere where a script would have been appropriate also. Acutally I combine them, `/usr/local/[s]bin/` is where the "single step" scripts are and the Makefile is in the working directory of the service in question.

Actually I have used them a lot more for the above reasons than for build systems - that is if you don't count latex and builds from upstream.

Comment: +1 for managing your DNS config files

Comment: actuall I don't :) - I've long ago abandoned bind because of the syntax. I'm using either tinydns or powerdns both of which I find a lot better than bind :) -- I just remembered it because typos in the zonefiles where a really common pitfall

Answer (score 2):

Since we're pretty much a Ruby shop, I use Rake instead of Make. I've automated the following with Rake, and it shouldn't be too difficult to do these with Make:

EC2 node maintenance. Create and terminate instances.

Create a tarball and upload it to S3.

Deploy server configurations; mainly by calling rsync for directories and directly copying singleton files.

Convert Ruby DSL code into JSON data.

Handle software releases in a git repository (creating new branches, tags, etc).

Comment: +1 for rake, it's easier to use than make and you have the power of a scripting language

Answer (score 1):

sendmail.cf back in the 8.9 days if I recall.

Answer (score 0):

I used makefiles to handle XML transformation from DocBook sources.  That way I could pipeline all of the commands and do "make pdf" or "make wordml" from the same source depending on who the intended audience was.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing really. I find Makefile syntax to be horrible for most day-to-day tasks and I try to only interact with Makefiles when absolutely necessary. For system administration tasks, I don't see what they offer over a Bash or Python script. For building software, there are better build systems out there.

Comment: i don't see how a bash or python script would understand dependencies or if a file has actually been produced at an intermediate step without writing all these checks by hand

Answer (score 0):

I've used it to "print all notes since last printing" in a random notes directory:

```
printflag: *.txt
    printcmd $?
    echo "printcmd $?" > $@
```

I echoed the command into the flag file so I could just ". printflag" to reprint the same set if need be;

to maintain DNS / DHCP / etc. :

```
edit hosts.dat # maintain single file with all relevant info
make           # work copies for visual check, diffs, etc., if needed
make install   # put into deploy-from-here location
make deploy    # push changed files to servers
make restart   # restart appropriate server processes here and there
```

(or just "edit hosts.dat; make restart" for the foolishly brave)

and as a quick and dirty way to generate manual scripts for procedures -- that is, just use pseudo targets and have the makefile commands echo something along the lines of "do step Foo" -- when you need something more sophisticated than tsort

Answer (score 0):

I know some people used to use Makefile script instead of init scripts. This effectively made them run paralelly and define dependencies between steps.